# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::group_start()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developing codeigniter php web application. There are I got error like this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::group_start() in C:\wamp\www\ci_sock\application\models\customer_m.php on line 31

[image]

How to solve this. There are my `PHP` code below:

```
foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {

            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

There are 31 line `$this->db->group_start();` like this.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Can you try applying group_start() before the foreach and group_end after the loop?

Comment: please shear with code. I am not express in codeigniter.

Comment: it depends upon how you want to group them, there is or_group also available to group OR conditions separately
`>or_group_start()
                        ->where('b', 'b')
                        ->where('c', 'c')
                ->group_end()`

Comment: please write it down for these example. I want full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->or_group_start(); 
foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
        }
    }
   $this->db->or_group_end();
   $this->db->group_end();
```

*Note : I couldn't check execute this code at this moment*

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for this issue, please change your code to the following:

```
if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    // $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i); //last loop
                    // $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket


            }
```

Comment: if you comment $this->db->group_start();  it produce wrong result